# Read Write Image to MS Access Database in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I should build software gym. 
I want to attach a photo to each employee in a gym. 
So I followed the excellent guide on youtube that explains how to attach an image to the data. 
The problem is that when I attach the picture is attaching in a new line in the table and not the existing line

thank you!!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;


namespace gym
{
    public partial class Load_Save : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter;
        DataTable LocalDataTable = new DataTable();

        int rowPosition=0;
        int rowNumber=0;


        public Load_Save()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Load_Save_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              ConnectToDatabase();  
        }

        private void ConnectToDatabase()
        {
            DBConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data.mdb";  

            DBConnection.Open();

            DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Workers", DBConnection);

            DataAdapter.Fill(LocalDataTable);

            if(LocalDataTable.Rows.Count !=0)
            {
                rowPosition = LocalDataTable.Rows.Count;
            }
        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                btnSave.Enabled = true;

            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StoreData(ConvertImageToBytes(pictureBox1.Image));
        }

        private byte[] ConvertImageToBytes(Image InputImage)
        {
            Bitmap BmpImage = new Bitmap(InputImage);

            MemoryStream Mystream = new MemoryStream();

            BmpImage.Save(Mystream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            byte[] ImageAsBytes = Mystream.ToArray();

            return ImageAsBytes;
        }

        private void StoreData(byte[] ImageAsBytes)
        {

            if(DBConnection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
               DBConnection.Open();


            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Saving image at index: " + rowPosition.ToString());

                OleDbCommand oledbInsert = new OleDbCommand("Insert INTO Workers (id,firtsname,lastname,email,username,job,passw,permission,phone,dateofjoin,photo) VALUES('" + "','" + "','" + "','" + "','" + "','" + "','" + "','" + "','" + "','" + "',@Myphoto)", DBConnection);
                OleDbParameter imageParameter = oledbInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", SqlDbType.Binary);
                imageParameter.Value = ImageAsBytes;
                imageParameter.Size = ImageAsBytes.Length;

                int rowsAffected = oledbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("data stored succ in" + rowsAffected.ToString() + " ROW");
                rowPosition++;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
            finally 
            {
                RefreshDBCconnection();
            }
        }


        private void RefreshDBCconnection()
        {
            DBConnection.Close();
            LocalDataTable.Clear();
            ConnectToDatabase();
        }


    }
```

}

Comment: Have you considered, instead of watching youtube and consideing that "excellent" maybe - reading a book or reading the documentation?

Comment: I should submit the project within two months. 
And since I do not know the language (C#) and I should learn everything alone 
So yes on youtube there are people who do a great job!

Comment: Not alone - ask more questions. Do more projects. Youtube videos is partly good, partly bad... They may cover some very basic parts, but because of format they absolutly CAN'T explan something placed deep inside technology(about how thing REALY works) - only reference documentation and source can. Yes, with videos you can have get working result. But you will rarrety get answer to question "why is this working like that, and how it can work in another ways?". But it's nessary in programming.. MSDN, Technet, .NET reference source, Stackoverflow is better friends for programmer than youtube. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update something in your database, something that already exists, then in SQL-query you must use [UPDATE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845036%28v=office.15%29.aspx)(with id of old record)  instead of [INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834799%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Like so:

```
UPDATE Workers SET photo=@photo WHERE id=@old_id
```

Or as variant(nice works if you want to update multiple records/multiple fields at same time, and simplify insert/update code) - you can [BEGIN TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208950%28v=office.12%29.aspx), delete old record's with "DELETE", insert new one's using INSERT's with same id's, and then [COMMIT TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208950%28v=office.12%29.aspx).